# File operation is slower is there a faster look up method in Python?

Tags: numpy, scipy, python, python-2.7

I am storing the values of the form given below into a file:

```
143   800 'Ask'
213   457 'Comment'
424   800 'Hi'
```

The first column contains unique elements here.
However, the look up on the values of the first column is quite inefficient when I am storing it in file format, is there a more efficient way in Python for a faster look-up.
I am aware of dictionaries in python for accomplishing this, but I am looking for some other method. Since the data I have consits of trillions of records..therefore I can not keep them in dictionary in the RAM. Therefore, I am searching for some other method.
Also with each program exection the rows are going to be inserted in the case of databases, how to overcome that, an example of what I am getting confused about in databases is given below:

```
 143   800 'Ask'
 213   457 'Comment'
 424   800 'Hi'
 143   800 'Ask'
 213   457 'Comment'
 424   800 'Hi'
```

Comment: "File format" is not a very specific description of what you're doing now.  Any database that can create an index will provide relatively fast look-ups (depending on how many millions of records you're storing).

Comment: @LarryLustig I am searching of a pythonic way to accomplish the same, though I am aware of dictionary...but I am searching for some other method of accomplishing the same. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a full code example using `sqlite3`, showing how to initialise the database, put data into it, and get a single row of data out.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.execute("""CREATE TABLE Widget (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                     serial_number INTEGER,
                                     description TEXT);""")

my_data = [ [143, 800, 'Ask'],
            [213, 457, 'Comment'],
            [424, 800, 'Hi'] ]

for row in my_data:
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO Widget (id, serial_number, description) VALUES (?,?,?);" , row )

conn.commit() # save changes

res = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM Widget WHERE id=143")
row = res.next()
print row #prints (143, 800, u'Ask')
```

Note the use of the special filename `:memory:` to open a temporary database.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is probably called a "Database table" and an "Index". The classic approach is to have a supplementary file (index) which maps the keys of the data tuples in the table to absolute positions of the tuples in the file.

Comment: Do you know of a pre-rolled implementation of this for Python? (`sqlite3` would qualify.) Trying to do this from scratch sounds like an exciting way to generate bugs.

Comment: No idea. And it sound like an exciting way to write something new :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, you want to be able to search faster in the file itself, or with the file content in python? In the latter, use a dictionary with the unique elements as key.

```
values = {143:[800,'ask'], 213:[457,'Comment'], 424:[800:'Hi']}
```

Comment: @Niek de Klein I knew about this from of storing in dictionary but at times I don't have values for values[143][1] ie the string 'None' is stored in its place. Is there any other method to accomplish the same in python. Also thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: @aquavitae Is there any other way other than dictionaries in python for accomplising the same, I was aware of dictionaries...I am just searching for some other way. Thanks for replying

Comment: @aquavitae : dicts only allow unique keys, though, so if he wants to store two `None` records he's out of luck. The next best thing to use would be `sqlite` (rolling your own solution would smell to me like an exercise in wheel reinvention.)

Comment: @Li-aungYip It doesn’t sound like the *key* could be `None`. And if that was the case, the problem would be there in a relational database as well, when using it as the primary key.

Comment: Ah, sorry - didn't read it properly.  You could still use sqlite though, but create an index instead of a primary key field.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to look things up in a persistent store, use a database. One example is [sqlite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html), which is built-in.

Comment: The problem with databasis is that it will keep entering rows on each program execution...which is undesirable, as I want to see my new results on each program execution how to overcome this. Thanks a lot for answering

Comment: +1 for `sqlite`. As a bonus, if you use a real database, it will automatically enforce things like the uniqueness of the unique keys (which is useful for catching programming errors and maintaining consistency of your data.)

Comment: @user1172532: `sqlite3.open(':memory:')` opens a new, temporary `sqlite3` database which exists only for the lifetime of your python interpreter session / python script. "Database" does not necessarily imply "persistence" (and even then, a few "DROP TABLE" statements would wipe it clean.)

Answer (score 0):

> Also with each program exection the rows are going to be inserted

If you want to keep the storage in a file, the way you do it, then the simple solution to prevent duplicate entries from appearing the next execution would be to simply *truncate* the file first. You can do this, by opening it with the `w` flag:

```
f = open('filename', 'w')
# ...
f.close()
```

However it sounds as if you just want to store some data *while* the program is executed, i.e. you want to keep data around without making it persistent. If that’s the case, then I am wondering why you actually store the contents in a file.

The more obvious way, which is also pythonic (although it’s not special to Python), would be to keep it in a dictionary during the program execution. A dictionary is mutable, so you can change its content all the time: You can add new entries, or even update entries if you later get more information on them.

> I knew about this from of storing in dictionary but at times I don't have values for values[143][1] ie the string 'None' is stored in its place

That’s not a problem at all. You can easily store an entry with `143` as the key and `None` as its value, or even an array of `None` values:

```
>>> values[143] = [ None, None ]
```

That way, the dictionary will still remember that you entered the key, so a check if the key is in the dictionary will return true:

```
>>> 143 in values
True
```

> Is there any other way other than dictionaries in python for accomplising the same, I was aware of dictionaries...I am just searching for some other way.

No, there usually is only *one* way to do something right in Python, as also told by the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *“There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.”*

As such, no, there is probably not an appropriate way to use dictionaries without dictionaries. But then again, why are you searching for some other way? It does not sound to me, as if you have a good reason to do so, and if you have, you have to make sure that you explain why certain ways are undesirable for you to use.

Comment: Since I want that with each program execution the rows are going to be inserted...i can not use dictionaries for it. As here dictionaries will be kept in the RAM, and considering the data I am dealing with..which consists of trillions of entries...its not feasible to keep the data in the RAM, therefore I am searching for some other way. Thanks a lot for answering.